# Error processing complex json object of twitter with pig JsonLoader() of elephant-bird Jars

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, apache-pig, elephantbird

I wanted to process twitter json object with pig using elephant-bird jars for which i wrote the pig script as below.

```html
REGISTER '/usr/lib/pig/lib/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/usr/lib/pig/lib/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

A = LOAD '/user/flume/tweets/data.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myMap#'id' AS ID,myMap#'created_at' AS createdAT;
DUMP B;
```

which gave me error as below

```html
2015-08-25 11:06:34,295 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1439883208520_0177
2015-08-25 11:06:34,295 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A,B
2015-08-25 11:06:34,295 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: A[3,4],B[4,4] C:  R:
2015-08-25 11:06:34,303 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-08-25 11:06:34,303 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1439883208520_0177]
2015-08-25 11:07:06,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
2015-08-25 11:07:06,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1439883208520_0177]
2015-08-25 11:07:09,458 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2015-08-25 11:07:09,458 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1439883208520_0177 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-08-25 11:07:09,459 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-08-25 11:07:09,667 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://trinityhadoopmaster.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-08-25 11:07:09,668 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at trinityhadoopmaster.com/192.168.1.135:8032
2015-08-25 11:07:09,678 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=FAILED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-08-25 11:07:09,779 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
2015-08-25 11:07:09,779 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-08-25 11:07:09,780 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.6.0   0.14.0  hdfs    2015-08-25 11:06:33     2015-08-25 11:07:09     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1439883208520_0177  A,B     MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed!    hdfs://trinityhadoopmaster.com:9000/tmp/temp1554332510/tmp835744559,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://trinityhadoopmaster.com:9000/user/flume/tweets/data.json"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://trinityhadoopmaster.com:9000/tmp/temp1554332510/tmp835744559"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1439883208520_0177


2015-08-25 11:07:09,780 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2015-08-25 11:07:09,787 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B. Backend error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
Details at logfile: /tmp/pig-err.log
grunt>
```

which i have no clue on how to approach, can any one help me on this.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

```
REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar';

REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

REGISTER '/tmp/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';

REGISTER '/tmp/google-collections-1.0.jar';

REGISTER '/tmp/json-simple-1.1.jar';
```

It works.